# java.lang.Error - Unresolved compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm getting this weird error,

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The code of method render(GameContainer, StateBasedGame, Graphics) is 
    exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

People have been telling me to break down the bytes or something and I don't know what they mean or how to do it render is a void that has graphics g, and state based game and game container. Could someone explain to me how to fix it?

Comment: The method `render` is to large (the byte code exceeds the 64k limit).  You need to break it apart it better managed code segments.

Comment: Refactor. Split out parts in their own methods.

Comment: @user1569948 - I'm definitely curious how you managed to do this?  Q: How many lines does your class have?  Q: do you have any really long "switch" blocks?  Or a lot of inner classes?  Methods that span more than 50 lines?  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#40222), talking about classes:

> The value of the code_length item must be less than 65536.

This means that you can't go over 64kb of raw bytecode.

In any case I think that this is the least of your problems since you shouldn't reach that limit at all in a single file. Just take out classes:

- if you are using inner classes just extract them to separated files
- if you are not using inner classes then there should be something really wrong in the code since this means really longs methods, consider refactoring methods